# Run a shell script and pass arguments from inside mathematica

Tags: scripting, arguments

Is it possible to run a shell script AND pass it arguments from Mathematica? I have  searched thoroughly and been unable to find a way to do this.

I want to avoid having to write a .wls for this particular instance, although I am beginning to fear I may have to.

Comment: How about `Run` and `RunProcess`?

Comment: Also `StartProcess` is nice if you need to dynamically interact with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can experiment with this code:

```
RunProcess[{"C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe", "/C", "cd"}, "StandardOutput"] // FullForm
RunProcess[{"script.bat", "arg1", "arg2"}, "StandardOutput"] // FullForm
```

under Windows, or with UNIX use:

```
RunProcess[{"/bin/sh", "-c", "pwd"}, "StandardOutput"] // FullForm
RunProcess[{"/bin/sh", "-c", "script.sh arg1 arg2", "StandardOutput"] // FullForm
```